# Angular IIS Deployment - ‘src’ attribute of <script> element is not a valid URI:

Tags: angular

I am attempting to deploy an Angular 7 app to IIS. The app is in a subdirectory. I referenced this excellent [article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7) on the subject. While it appears to be working better then my previous attempts, the page fails to load with the following error messages:

```
‘src’ attribute of <script> element is not a valid URI: “runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js” index.html:14:1
‘src’ attribute of <script> element is not a valid URI: “es2015-polyfills.c5dd28b362270c767b34.js” index.html:14:1
‘src’ attribute of <script> element is not a valid URI: “polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js” index.html:14:1
‘src’ attribute of <script> element is not a valid URI: “main.13a837ca016c8bacb03a.js” index.html:14:1
```

To build the app, I ran:
`ng build --base-href='/new/team/' --prod`.

The app is hosted under a directory called `new/team` on the IIS server. The web.config file is placed in the same directory as the app's `index.html`, `favicon.ico` and other core files. The web.config is a direct copy from the aforementioned article:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: show me the content of index.html that generate in prod mode